# Intellisense prefers oldest TypeScript version in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017, intellisense

I have a question regarding Intellisense in Visual Studio 2017.
I have installed the TypeScript SDK, with its latest Version (currently 2.5.3).

This is my folder structure:

[image: TypeScript folder structure]

When i now use Intellisense it offers me the oldest version:

[image: Intellisense offer]

In the project properties I set the TypeScript version to 2.4.

How could I tell Visual Studio to take the newest version, or take the version that is stated in my tsconfig.json file, instead of the oldest one?

I am thankful for any hint that leads me to the right direction!

Btw, moving the 2.1 folder out of the Typescript folder works, but i do not think that this would be the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2017, TypeScript updates are applied slightly differently than in Visual Studio 2015, however you can now have multiple TypeScript versions installed and choose specific versions for each of your projects. For more detail information, please check this doc: [Updating TypeScript in Visual Studio 2017](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Updating-TypeScript-in-Visual-Studio-2017)

For VS 2017 version 15.3 and later, the TypeScript version is bound to individual projects. Right click the project name>**Properties>TypeScript Build** tab and you can change TypeScript version to the desired version or "use latest available".

For VS 2017 version 15.2 and before, please go to **Tools > Options > Text Editor > JavaScript/TypeScript > IntelliSense** and change Use TypeScript version to your desired version.

Comment: Thanks, but it was already set to 2.4 beforehand. I'll update the question text.

Comment: @Muarl, since you have the 2.5 version, please have a try with other versions to check if this issue persist or not. Meanwhile, you can re-run the VS 2017 installer as administrator and choose 'Repair' to repair it.

Comment: No highlights and intelligence shows in Visual Studio 2015 for type Script